# Create Loading animation before navigating to another page and disable all conrols on it during animation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

I have a button on Page 1 and when the button click event occurs, I had to do some process that takes around 2-3 seconds. So, I want to Put a Loading Image in Center and disable all other controls on the Page 1.

I tried using `UpdatePanel` :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Unnamed1_Click" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label" ID="lbl"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" >

        <ProgressTemplate>

        <div id="IMGDIV1" align="center" valign="middle" runat="server" style="position: absolute;visibility:visible;vertical-align:middle;border-style:none;border-color:black;background-color:transparent;">

        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ajax-loader (1).gif" />
        </div>

        </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

But the controls did not get disabled. Any Solution or Javascript ??

Also I want that it should work if want to stay on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

why dont yu use telerik radgrid loading panel ?

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-center-loadingpanel.html

Comment: I am not familiar with this thing, do you have any other solution ??

Comment: ammmm no, I use only telerik loading panels. I dont have much idea about default loading panels... wait I'll study them now

Comment: I found an easy javascript for it, exactly what i needed -- http://www.dotnet-developer.de/2008/04/aspnet/display-please-wait-popup/